# Saving user's file path in PrimeFace's p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, path

I am working on a PrimeFaces5 application where the work-routine described as follows:

1. User uploads a custom file.
2. Invokes some stuff on the app related to the file.
3. Edits the file in his local machine, and does step 1 again.

For this purpose I'm using p:fileUpload in basic mode.
I want to make the user's work easier by remembering the path of the file in the user's machine so he'll just press the upload button (instead of pressing browse and search the file again), but I can't figure out how to find and store the path of the uploaded file in my backing bean.

The browser I use for the app is Chrome.

Sorry for bad English. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The user is not going to change the path of the file, he just modifies it and uploads again, so I want that the p:uploadFile component will remember the file.

Comment: Sounds like the browser's fault. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: The problem is that the only choice of browser I have is Chrome.